# Toggle multiple div elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

On my page I'm currently doing something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/FBCSt/6/ I really don't know why, but in Chrome I got some strange issues with that - sometimes the contents of the div elements are not loaded correctly. In IE, Safari and Firefox it work fine, but as I said, in Chrome it is causing some trouble.

That's why I want to know, if there is a more sleek way to do this? (There are three buttons, every one is assigned to one div. Only one div should be visible)

I am thankful for every answer =)

EDIT: Thanks everybody. This is the solution. It works well =)

"a better way: jsfiddle.net/FBCSt/13 – @Mohammed ElSayed 20 mins ago"

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel? http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/

Comment: @MetalFrog You aren't really suggesting to include 100k of jQuery UI code to replace his 80 bytes of jsFiddle code are you?

Comment: I got the bug what is the problem. Even if you do a show and hide there is a class with which there is a css `display:none` called .content which makes all three still invisible in chrome. I think you should not put them using css class use document.ready for that actually.

Comment: @AlienWebguy Good point, but [oh come on](http://jqueryui.com/download). ~26KB if you only need "tabs". Plus, the OP **might** already be using **jQuery UI**.

Comment: Every kb counts these days, especially when many visitors are using [obnoxiously slow] 3G and don't have unlimited data plans. Would you say the same thing about a 16x16 icon which the designer provided as 26k and looked just as good at 500 bytes? No, you'd compress it. No-brainer.

Comment: Says the guy who forces users to open an http connection to this file: http://solidaredesign.com/apps/page/theme/js/home.js  It's ok to  not understand these things, but you ridicule yourself by masking ignorance with sarcasm.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/FBCSt/10/

Comment: This is awesome! Thank you so much @MohammedElSayed ! And thanks to all the others, too =)

Answer (score 0):

> In IE, Safari and Firefox it work fine, but as I said, in Chrome it is
>   causing some trouble.

I really don't see an issues when testing under *Google Chrome 19.0.1084*. But in any case,

> That's why I want to know, if there is a more sleek way to do this?

Yep, there is. Since one of your tags is **jQuery**, I suggest you take a look at **jQuery UI**'s [tabs](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/).

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use show() instead of toggle()? Maybe the issue is related to using toggle(). And you can combine the elements to be hidden: For example,

```
$('#page2,#page3').hide();    
$('#page1').show();
```

Or as nicely put by Mohammad,

```
$('#page1').show().siblings().hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

I have working solution on this url : [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/QJs1EcDV) it works in chrome and also in FF.also it will work even if you add 1000 id with page#100 but still it will not have too much code. thanks.

Comment: It was a minor code change. The Problem was you were trying to handle the element using jquery using ids but it has already applied display:none using class `.content`

Answer (score 0):

Like Abody97 said: try JQuery UI tabs

If you're looking for a "more sleek" way of doing this, try this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/NCbW6/

It doesn't bother with specific ids for each element so you can add as many as you'd like without changing the JS.